# Attributes in c++ and their use

Tags: c++, attributes

The most recent c++ feature(that is also quite modern) that I found about is attributes. They seem quite useful for signalling the compiler, but apart from that, what other more specific uses can attributes have? How can custom attributes be created and used and what is the main idea behind the use of c++ Attributes? If the topic is too broad, im particularly interested in attributes with functions.
By attributes I mean these: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes

Comment: The very first sentence in the quoted article: "Introduces **implementation-defined** attributes..." Consult the documentation for the specific compiler you use. Standard C++ doesn't provide any means to define custom attributes.

Comment: "Attributes provide the unified standard syntax for implementation-defined language extensions, such as the GNU and IBM language extensions" oh yes, it says implementation defined there somewhere,... right..? Welp, must mean they are implementation specific, guess I'm not answering anything then.

Comment: They're a lot like pragmas in that respect - though the standard defines more attributes than it does pragmas.

Comment: As a very good video on attributes I recommend the following(after some research): https://youtu.be/teUA5U6eYQY

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Attributes (that is, attributes as a feature of the C++ language, not compiler-specific `__declspec` or `__attribute__` attributes) are kind of a C++ hack. They're a solution to meta-problems with the evolution of the C++ language.

For example, keywords. There's a lot of C++ code out there, and any new version of the language that adds new keywords needs to avoid breaking any code that might use that keyword for an identifier. So any language feature that might want to spell something out explicitly has a really high bar for passing standardization. That is, it'd had better be worth it.

But attributes are cheap; they don't conflict with any existing code. Consider wanting to declare that a function does not return normally (ie: always throws an exception or calls `std::terminate` or whatever). That feature it doesn't really govern the behavior of the program; it's more an indicator to the compiler/user about how that function is going to behave. So it's not a feature worth breaking the code of someone who just so happened to name a variable `noreturn`.

But you can have the `[[noreturn]]` attribute, since that won't break anybody's code.

Another meta-problem attributes solve is "fixing" things that maybe weren't good ideas in the first place. For example, `case` labels in `switch` statements automatically fall-through to the next one if you don't explicitly `break`. While fall-through behavior is useful, it's the wrong behavior to have as a *default*, since 90+% of the time, you intend to `break`.

But you can't go and change how `case` labels work and introduce a `fallthrough` keyword. That would break everybody's code that already uses the implicit fall-through behavior.

But you can add a `[[fallthrough]]` attribute. It doesn't mean anything within the language, but if a compiler sees it, then it can know that you meant to fall-through to the next label. Furthermore, you can now turn on compiler warnings about fall-through behavior, so that any fall-through that happens *without* the `[[fallthrough]]` attribute will give you a warning. And you can even choose to make that warning an error, thus effectively "fixing" the language. For you.

Most C++ attributes are like that: tags for code that are too trivial/non-functional to bother burning a keyword for, or indicating something useful about the code to the compiler that isn't really part of the langauge.